# MongoDB and HBase consistency difference? Transactions?

Tags: mongodb, hbase, consistency

I heard multiple times companies like HBase strong consistency. I read about HBase and like it. Then I thought about mongodb write and the difference between then. After looking it up MongoDB seems to have strong consistency as well. But is it consistent? It appears HBase has transactions and MongoDB doesn't. I'm a bit confused. All I found were simple inserts and updates for them both and explanation how thet replicate. I haven't seen transactions.

What are MongoDB and HBase consistency difference? I believe HBase has ACID transactions, does mongodb have anything to deal with multiple inserts or is it expected that everything should be in a single document? (I can't think of a reason why thats not good enough atm).

For consistency and replication reasons what are the difference and why might one choose one over the other?

Comment: this page http://hbase.apache.org/acid-semantics.html specifically says HBase does NOT have ACID (but some properties of ACID which is the same thing you can say for MongoDB)  Maybe you can describe specifically *which* ACID properties are critical to your application and that will make the question easier to answer specifically.

Answer (score 3):

I can only answer for MongoDB.

MongoDB has no server-side transactions. This does not mean all inserts are expected to be one document because multi-level nesting of documents 3 or 5 levels deep can become a pain to manage. It is more that it simply is not supported at the current time and the community using MongoDB have personally opted to vote and put their support behind different features.

That being said MongoDB can do client side transactions: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/ however since this is not isolated to the database server itself it is still open to certain fail scenarios that could effect it's ability to create an integral transaction.

That being said, if you were to code a deamon of sorts that would manage your transactional queries across a cluster I do not see any reason why it would be less durable than what HBase could offer.

I cannot speak for the HBase consistency since I personally have not actually used HBase in a production environment however MongoDB does have all the normal levels of read and write consistency for single queries you would expect of HBase and SQL allowing a safe insert level that can actually replicate to other nodes of your cluster before your application gets a success callback for the operation. Infact the default setup of MongoDB is not eventually consistent, however you can make it as such.

I have personally heard, on here and other places, that the preference between consistency and replication between the two is subjective and comes down to your scenario, hardware, platform and other specifics that we probably cannot go into fully here.

Comment: Does 'client side transactions' mean implement it yourself? I read the link and it looks like you need to implement it yourself and it looks very gross :x. I'm unsure if you're saying you can insert multiple documents at once (i guess in an atomic way)?

Comment: @acidzombie24 Indeed it is a bit gross, and yea it is in your app code so you cannot atomically insert multiples of documents. This of course changes the lock dynamics that would also occur since instead of locking atomically, as you would for a acid transaction, you would instead use the (v2.2) DB level write lock for insertions and the atomic lock for updates. Not to mention it requires a separate table/collection to track the update which again is managed from the app code and not the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer for the hbase side.
First you can only have transaction in hbase per row. you have 2 kind of atomic operations.

1. Check & Put.
2. Atomic counter

If you want the ability to write a transaction for several rows.
There are 2 open sources that I can recommend for you:
1. https://github.com/VCNC/haeinsa. this open source in my opinion is the best I found currently. it uses the check & put and does some kind of 2 phase commit on the rows.

2. https://github.com/caskdata/tephra. This open source combines client server and co-processor. and in my opinion might be that is not scale since the server is a bottleneck.

also 2 phase commit. and I guess for very fast transactions it might be faster than haeinsa.

Answer (score 0):

As of v4.0 (coming in summer 2018), MongoDB will support multi-document ACID transactions. Sign up for the beta program at: https://www.mongodb.com/transactions